# Showing two graphs are isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory

How can I show these two graphs are isomorphic. I am thinking  H1 and H2 aRE[image]

I think H1 and H2 are not isomorphic. Because there is a not a vertex H2  that has degree 4 and is connected to vertex of degree 1 and degree 3 and degree 4. So H1 is not isomorphic to H2.

But I am not sure how to tell for G1.

Comment: $G_1$ is isomorphic to $G_2$: pull the two inner vertices (except the very center one) to the sides, then rotate and go from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic. To see this requires some playing around and visualizing, and to prove it requires a bit of tedious labeling. You need to label the vertices of both graphs in a certain way so that $(a,b)$ is an edge of one if and only if it is an edge of another. Since this is a small finite graph, it is probably easiest to list the vertices and edges in both and brute force this proof.

Note that, if two graphs are isomorphic, then their degree sequences are the same (as you suggested using different language). But $H_1$ has degree sequence $4,3,3,3,3,3,\ldots$ and $H_2$ starts out with $4,3,3,2,\ldots$ (hope I counted that right). Thus they cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.

Comment: Nearly. $H_1$ starts $4,4,3,3,3...$ and $H_2$ starts $4,4,4,3,3,...$ but conclusions are unchanged.